# How do I make a QUERY function with a dynamic variable inside of my google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello SO Community and thank you in advance for your assistance.  I am constructing some streamlined automated sales reporting for my company where the data sources are rooted in Google Sheets.  I want to be able to customize a report based on a dynamic variable in a QUERY function within my apps script.  I am sure this is a very basic answer but I am a bit of a code cobbling novice and do not have the the education to easily sort this out.

In the QUERY the variable I am looking for is in column B, and as of now I am only able to type it in manually \'Artist Name\'.  I tried to use a variety of quotes and + to insert a dynamic var instead of Artist Name but am having errors returned after the script runs.

```
function exampleOfHowItCurrentlyWorks {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var setQuery = ss.getSheetByName('printLog').getRange('A1').setFormula('=QUERY(A1:I,"Select A,B Where B Contains \'Artist Name\' ",1)');

}

function exampleOfHowItShouldWork {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var artist1 = ss.getSheetByName('theme').getRange('B1').getValue();
  var setQuery = ss.getSheetByName('printLog').getRange('A1').setFormula('=QUERY(A1:I,"Select A,B Where B Contains \'artist1\' ",1)');

}
```

The basic functionality is I would like to be able to go to my sheet name titled 'theme' and change Range 'B1' to Michaelangelo, and the query returns results where column B contains Mihchaelangelo…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function exampleOfHowItShouldWork {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var artist1 = ss.getSheetByName('theme').getRange('B1').getValue();
  var setQuery = ss.getSheetByName('printLog').getRange('A1')
    .setFormula('=QUERY(A1:I,"Select A,B Where B Contains \'' + artist1 + '\' ",1)');
}
```

Close the string with an unescaped single quote, and use + to concatenate the strings together.

Depending on why you're doing this (e.g., if you just want to have B1 be a 'search box' you will type the name into), it might be easier to just do this through Sheets without Apps Script:

`=QUERY(A1:I, "Select A, B Where B contains '" & B1 & "'", 1)`

Other sheets can be accessed by, e.g., `'theme'!B1`.

Comment: This definitely deserves a lot of upvotes! Thanks, been searching everywhere.